# Concluding a factor group is abelian based off of order. $|D_4/Z(D_4)|=4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Concluding a factor group is abelian based off of order. $D_4/Z(D_4)$

I don't know how to input tables yet. A little background. I have this table in which I need to find the center and the commutator subgroup of $D_4$ I've found the center to contain two elements based on the table. Namely it is $Z(D_4)=\{\rho_0, \rho_2\}$ this is a normal subgroup. Here is where I get slightly thrown off. $|D_4/Z(D_4)|=4$ Which is not surprising. $|D_4| = 8, |Z(D_4)|=2$. Are factor groups of even order abelian? I need to conclude that the factor group is abelian then I know that $C(D_4) \leq Z(D_4)$

Comment: You can use the theorem that any group of order $p^2$ (where $p$ is a prime) is abelian. Or, you can use the fact that any group of order $4$ is isomorphic to $C_4$ or $C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: ah, 2 is prime $2^2 = 4$ thus abelian. Thank you!!